# IP video stream to HDMI

Tags: vlc, hdmi, iptv

I need to stream a video via VLC from my computer, but i need to convert it from Ethernet to HDMI, for further distribution, i have [this product](http://questtel.com/item.php?id=10&product=5)

So, Are there any methods to convert IP to HDMI with keeping video stream compatible with that extender?

Answer (score 0):

The product you reference, which is essentially a wireless HDMI link, takes a standard HDMI input.

You should only need to connect your HDMI output on your computer to the input on this device to have the video play on the screen connected to another instance of the product at the other end of the wireless HDMI connection.